ZooKeeper zkCli does not use the logs directory as configured
I am running ZooKeeper latest stable 3.8.4 release. I installed it in /usr/local/zookeeper/ and configured /usr/local/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg to specify
dataDir=/var/zookeeper

The logging configuration in /usr/local/zookeeper/conf/logback.xml is
<property name="zookeeper.log.dir" value="logs" />
<property name="zookeeper.log.file" value="zookeeper.log" />

With these definitions I expected that all logs files will be in /var/zookeeper/logs.
The ZooKeeper service indeed seems to do that. However, ZK CLI does not. Running /usr/local/zookeeper/bin/zkCli.sh creates a logs directory in any directory from which it is invoked.
Is that the expected behavior?
Is that healthy that log files are not be consolidated?
After noticing that I added CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/zookeeper/conf/ but it did not change the behavior. I think that this is a requirement of LOGback.
It seems that there are 3 log files. The following 2 are created by the ZK service:
/var/zookeeper/logs/zookeeper.log
/usr/local/zookeeper/logs/zookeeper-zookeeper-server-host1.out

and the following created by ZK CLI in any working directory it happens to be invoked in:
./logs/zookeeper.log

Is there any documentation for the purpose of each of these logs?

First and foremost, this is not an answer. I am unable to reproduce your case where zkCli.sh creates a log directory in the directory from where it is invoked

There is no log directory

If you tell how you have installed ZK and the configuration, it will help.
EDIT - Additional Information
The location of the log directory is set in the bin/zkEnv.sh which is invoked by bin/zkCli.sh The log file is for the CLI only. The routine that starts CLI is

One way to change the log directory is to add a line in the zkCli.sh redefining the 'ZOO_LOG_DIR', that would work.
Refer the above sh files.
EDIT - 2

/usr/local/zookeeper/logs/zookeeper-zookeeper-server-host1.out

This is the console trace (of sorts) file if you run ZK as a service. This is more or less a common feature, Tomcat does that too.

/var/zookeeper/logs/zookeeper.log

I have never used this, however, it seems the same output as above is available in the file. Refer: this post

./logs/zookeeper.log

I cannot comment on this, as the file generated during test is zookeeper_audit.log. The details of which are available here

It was installed exactly as specified here. Can you try to run it, not remotely, but on that computer you are connecting to?

Yes, it does create a directory logs when connecting to localhost with a file zookeeper_audit.log. I shall check

Added an edit with more information

Thank you. This explains the mechanics, and I really want to accept your answer, but it does not answer the questions in my original post. In short, what is the purpose of each of the three logs files? Is it okay that zkCLi does not log to where  zkServer logs? Is it okay that zkCLI create a new logs dir wherever it is invoked (there is no zkCLI single log across invocations)?

Added another edit
